# navigation menu css styling submenu gaps in ie7

Tags: css, menu, navigation, internet-explorer-7

I have a navigation menu generated by Wordpress, meaning I have pretty much no control on how it is output.

I have used css to style it the way I want with on-hover submenus, but it looks off in IE7. It does not have any problems in other browsers.

The main menu may seem off even in browsers that work because I am using `@fontface` on my website but did not include in the jsFiddle. The main problem is the gaps between the submenu items.

I have tried vertically aligning the submenu `li` and `a`, but it either made it worse or didn't fix the problem.

I have replicated the problem here: [link removed]

---

If I add

```
#menu-header .sub-menu a { height: 100%; }
```

It fixes the vertical gap problem, but the items are no longer the same width.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following :

```
#menu-header .sub-menu a { zoom: 1; }
```

This will remove the gap, but items will be the same width as the inner content.

I had the same problem some time ago. What I did was, create a container `div` inside the `li`. so that longer text can wrap, and set a static width. You can even use jQuery to adjust the widths of each dropdown dynamically, but that a whole different story.

**Few references :**

http://work.arounds.org/issue/20/removing-gaps-between-list-items-containing-anchor/

http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200610/closing_the_gap_between_list_items_in_ie/

http://www.belafontecode.com/3-ways-to-get-rid-of-spaces-in-list-item-navigation-in-ie6/

Comment: Checked all the methods. `zoom: 1` leaves the widths varied. Setting a px width along with `zoom: 1` would mean the menu had no flexibility (longer words will just overflow). Floating the list items would also cause varied widths. Bottom border does not work.

Comment: I guess I'll have to settle with fixed width. I looked at Twenty Eleven theme for Wordpress and they've done the same thing.

Comment: You can set the fixed width css just for IE7 and lower. So good browser will have varied widths. See http://css-tricks.com/132-how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/ and use IE7 and lower. :)

Comment: I'm trying to avoid using IE only stylesheets. I don't want to litter my header with all these conditional statements. Thanks anyway.